# Is $-e^{i\pi} = 1$?

Tags: complex-numbers, exponential-function

Since $e^{i\pi} = \cos \pi + i\sin \pi = -1,$ a suspicious argument is to proceed to conclude that
$$-e^{i\pi} = 1.$$
However, this leads to 
$$-e^{i\pi} = e^{0}.$$
Is the above reasoning wrong?

Comment: No. $e^z$ is periodic with period $2\pi i$.
$$e^0=e^{2\pi i}=e^{\pi i}\cdot e^{\pi i}=-e^{\pi i}.$$

Comment: Why is it suspicious to conclude from $e^{\pi i} = -1$ that $-e^{\pi i} = 1$? In any case, $z \to e^z$ is not injective as a map $\mathbb{C} \to \mathbb{C}$.

Comment: Thanks. You mean that argument is admissible?

Comment: @anomaly: Thanks; but that is the question

Comment: Would you conclude from $-(-1)^2=(-1)^3$ that $2=3$?

Comment: Not in provoking tone, etiquette. According to this site's law, being a dumb question is not a condition for downvoting.

Comment: @egreg: I am telling you; Do not talk like it is too trivial to bother you. Nobody forces you to look at this question.

Comment: @Chou, what are you getting upset about? egreg is trying to help. (Unless comments have been deleted...)

Comment: @TonyK: No upset, never mind. I think the definition of trying to help varies from person to person. The comments you are interested are unimportant in the sense that they are not relevant to the question itself.

Comment: @Chou I'm sorry if you found my comment offensive, I surely didn't mean it. Nor I wanted to say your question is dumb or too trivial and in fact I didn't downvote it. I was pointing out that you neglected the minus sign.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's correct. There's nothing wrong with the above reasoning. Is it equally wrong that $e^{2\pi n i}=1$ for all $n\in\mathbb{Z}$? The Euler formula you quoted shows that the exponential function, as a complex function, is periodic. Namely, it is non-injective, or $e^z=e^w$ does not imply $z=w$.

Answer (score 2):

There's nothing suspicious if you remember that $$e^{i\pi} = -1 \iff -(e^{i\pi}) = 1$$ and being clear that this is not to say  $$(-e)^{i\pi} = 1$$

So there is nothing wrong with $$-(e^{i\pi}) = e^{0}.$$  But that is not to say that $i\pi = 0$.