# Linear Algebra Resources

Tags: linear-algebra, online-resources

This is not a specific question so much as an open request for learning resources. I look linear algebra about a year ago, but have since forgotten a lot of it and wanted to refresh on some of the major concepts before I begin taking upper division classes (I've been told it comes up depending on the class and the area of focus). Can anyone share any online or interactive  resources you know of to review matrices, matrix operations, invertibility, linear independence/dependence, mapping, determinants, eigenvalues and eigenvectors, vector spaces and subspaces, basis and change of basis, etc. ? Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 2):

Check "Essence of linear algebra" by 3Blue1Brown on youtube (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fNk_zzaMoSs&list=PLZHQObOWTQDPD3MizzM2xVFitgF8hE_ab).

Comment: Thank you Irene! I'll check it out

Comment: use `[something](link)` to get [something](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1198428/%20https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2767723/%20https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/341214/%20https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1198428/), press Ctrl+L while writing the answer to insert a link